# Why is replacing conditionals with polymorphism useful?

Tags: python, oop, design-patterns, polymorphism, conditional-statements

There's one thing that has always stumped me about "replacing a conditional with polymorphism" as shown on [refactoring.guru](https://refactoring.guru/replace-conditional-with-polymorphism#:%7E:text=In%20them%2C%20create%20a%20shared,depending%20on%20the%20object%20class.) which I would like to clarify. I have re-created the example in python below:

**IF STATEMENT CODE**

```
def get_speed(bird):
    base_speed = 10

    if bird == "AfricanBird":
        return base_speed * 2 - 10
    elif bird=="EuropeanBird":
        return base_speed * 1.85 - 12
    elif bird=="NorwegianBlue":
        return base_speed * 2.5 - 11
    else:
        raise ValueError("Bird type invalid")

if __name__=="__main__":
    b = "EuropeanBird"
    speed = get_speed(b)
    print(speed)
```

**REPLACING IF STATEMENT WITH POLYMORPHISM**

```
from abc import abstractmethod, ABC

class Bird(ABC):
    def get_base_speed(self):
        return 10

    @abstractmethod
    def get_speed(self):
        pass

class AfricanBird(Bird):
    def get_speed(self):
        return self.get_base_speed()*2-10

class EuropeanBird(Bird):
    def get_speed(self):
        return self.get_base_speed()*1.85-12

class NorwegianBlue(Bird):
    def get_speed(self):
        return self.get_base_speed()*2.5-11

if __name__=="__main__":
    # This *still* has to be specified by the user somewhere.
    # For example in a GUI or input text file.
    b = "EuropeanBird"

    # Here is the if statement again!!
    if b == "AfricanBird":
        b = AfricanBird()
    elif b=="EuropeanBird":
        b = EuropeanBird()
    elif b=="NorwegianBlue":
        b = NorwegianBlue()
    else:
        raise ValueError("Bird type invalid")

    print(b.get_speed())
```

I get the part where polymorphism adds generality by allowing you to inherit from a base class and redefine the behavior instead of adding a new branch in the `if` statement. However, at the end of the day you still need to make a decision somewhere in your main code for *which* implementation of your base class to use (line 26 in my second example), which forces the `if` statement to reappear.

Am I missing the point? Is there any way of completely eliminating the conditional statement in the client code?

Comment: If you vote to close could you please explain why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the IF STATEMENT variant, the cases *must* be handled alongside the computation. In the POLYMORPHISM variant, the cases *can* be handled as early as receiving the input, but could also be pushed arbitrarily further along. Using Polymorphism, the case decision and result are decoupled; one could even re-use the same decision to derive multiple results.

In short, both require to make the decision *somewhere* but Polymorphism allows choosing this somewhere.

---

While logically, *something* has to conditionally switch between the cases, this can be done without explicitly enumerating `if` branches.

The simplest means is to have a table from identifier to type. The base class can encapsulate this:

```py
class Bird(ABC):
    _birdies = {}
    _base_speed = 10

    @classmethod
    def breed(cls, kind: str):
        """Create a new bird of a given kind"""
        return cls._birdies[kind]()

    # register subclasses for lookup on definition
    def __init_subclass__(cls):
        Bird._birdies[cls.__name__] = cls

    @property
    @abstractmethod
    def speed(self):
        raise NotImplementedError

class AfricanBird(Bird):
    @property
    def speed(self):
        return self._base_speed * 2 - 10

class EuropeanBird(Bird):
    @property
    def speed(self):
        return self._base_speed * 1.85 - 12

Bird.breed("AfricanBird")  # <__main__.AfricanBird at 0x1106d1fa0>
```

Note that the class is only used as a frontend to hide the table. There is no polymorphism used here other than assuming that all subclasses can be interchangeably constructed without arguments.

Comment: So, in reality, there is no way of completely eliminating the conditional...? Is that what I am supposed to take from this? Are there any design patterns which can alleviate what I am doing in `__main__` for my second example?

Comment: @user32882 If your code has (logical) branches, *something* has to implement them. Alternatives to ``if`` are lookup tables (``tps = {"AfricanBird": AfricanBird, ...}`` and then ``instance = tps[name]()``) and dynamic trial (technically simple but too long for a comment) but ultimately they are functionally equivalent to "making a decision", aka a conditional.

Comment: @user32882 I have added an example of encapsulating a dynamically extended lookup table in the base class.

Answer (score 2):

In your example, you are converting a mere string to a full hierarchy of classes. As all what if required is handling a string, and as the input is that string, the polymorphism adds nothing except learning.

Things are different when various objects are created internally, and when those objects have some common behaviour with specificities. In fact the choice should arise at conception time, before writing any code line. You analyse what *objects* are to be processed, and what behaviour they will have to implement. At that point, the possible hierarchies  of classes should arise.

In fact, replacing a bunch of conditional with polymorphism should only occur if you have skipped the modeling phase in development, and find yourself consistently repeating the same conditional throughout your code. I have been using Python, Java and C++ for decades, and have never replaced conditionals with polymorphism: either the model exhibits a hierarchy *at conception time*, and it has to be implemented first, or there are no underlying objects and polymorphism will only add an useless complexity.

TL/DR: if you find yourself replacing conditionals with polymorphism, it just mean that you have written code without first thinking about what you wanted to develop and how you should to it.

Comment: Starting from legacy code developed by someone else (a scientist), who has no concept of OOP and good design is a common occurence in industry. There's nothing wrong with that. If you have been coding in those languages without ever doing this sort of replacement then I would argue that you are not the best person to answer this question? Finally, refactoring.guru (and indeed the GoF book) does not think that replacing conditionals with polymorphism introduces useless complexity, so I have to disagree with that.

Comment: I have had to port Fortran IV (no concept of OOP) code into C++. The high level parts were rewritten from scratch to be able to better structure the application with OO modeling. Only low-level (computation) routines were translated a minima. IMHO refactoring using OOP a code that was written in a spaghetti style with little to no tests could be harder than rewritting it from scratch. But you are right on one point, this is no more than my opinion :-)